# How do I add an additional resource action to my routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a resource named Volunteers:

```
class VolunteersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    #@volunteers = Volunteer.all()
    @volunteers = Volunteer.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @volunteer = Volunteer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @volunteer = Volunteer.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Volunteer.new(volunteer_params)

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def destroy
    @volunteer = Volunteer.find(params[:id])
    @volunteer.destroy
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end

  def search
    @volunteers = Volunteer.search params[:search]
  end

private

  def volunteer_params
    params.require(:volunteer).permit(:forename, :surname)
  end

end
```

I have added an additional action called search but I'm having issues mapping it in my routes file:

```
root 'home#index'
resources :volunteers
```

How do I map to the search action (including params)?

Answer (score 13):

There is an example in the route file itself:

```
  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end
```

You need to add the `search` method as a post (or whatever is appropriate) option for the resource, you can either add it to collection or member - collection methods won't look for a specific item id in the url, which is appropriate for a search method.

```
resources :volunteers do 
  collection do
    post :search
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to mention that I want `volunteers/1/search` to map to `search` action?

Comment: @lokesh add `get  'search'` to the `member do` block under volunteers.